# Do we have option to connect perl to MS access db in unix/linux platform?

Tags: perl, ms-access, dbi, dbd

I thinks windows os it is possible. But I'm not sure about unix/linux. Is there any option to do that. Any one tried before.

Comment: A combination of `unixODBC` and `MDB Tools` would be a fairly typical approach, although I've only tried that route a couple of times with PHP and each attempt met with somewhat limited success.

Comment: Like Gord Thompson says - mdbtools is all there is. If you have to do it then you'll just have to hope it works well enough for you. If you can run a Windows VM to run Access on and extract data that way, then it's much easier. There's also a java-based library "jackcess" but I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You access a MS Access file using ODBC via Perl perl DBI and perl DBD::ODBC using the following methods:

1. MDB tools (as other have said) which is free
2. Using an [ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) commercial
3. Using a [Microsoft Access ODBC Driver for Linux/Unix](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html) commercial

As current maintainer of DBD::ODBC I've had people report a lot of problems with MDB tools but if you free this is your only choice.

(2) requires you install a service on the windows machine where your MS Access file is located and then it uses the MS Access ODBC Driver. It provides a client ODBC driver for Linux and Unix which talks to the service on the Windows machine.

(3) requires direct access to the MS Access file i.e., you need to have it accessible from the Linux/Unix machine either by copying it to the local disk or accessing it via SMB (samba and file sharing from Windows machine).